# Usage of the Adapter pattern and if it is correct

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, adapter

We have a tool that generates mapping code for stored procedures in our Oracle database.
I'll try to explain it as abstract as possible without any noise and therefore everything has been greatly simplified.

Let's say this is one part of our generated code:

```
public interface IDbMethodCaller
{
    IEnumerable<object> ExecuteMethodCall(string methodName, IEnumerable<string> parameters);
}

public class GeneratedSchemaContext
{
    private readonly IDbMethodCaller _dbMethodCaller;

    public GeneratedSchemaContext(IDbMethodCaller dbMethodCaller)
    {
        _dbMethodCaller = dbMethodCaller;
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> ExecuteSampleProcedure()
    {
        return _dbMethodCaller.ExecuteMethodCall("sample_procedure", new List<string>());
    }
}
```

We normaly have a standard class that we're using for data access purposes:

```
public class OracleDataContext
{
    public IEnumerable<object> ExecuteMethodCall(string methodName, IEnumerable<string> parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OracleDataContext.ExecuteMethodCall");

        return new List<object>();
    }
}
```

Now I want to use the above DataContext for the `GeneratedSchemaContext`. So how do I do this? The class itself cannot implement IDbMethodCaller because in other projects it doesn't know the interface (part of the generated code).

I thought about the adapter pattern and changed it a little bit:

```
public class OracleDataContextAdapter : OracleDataContext, IDbMethodCaller
{
    public new IEnumerable<object> ExecuteMethodCall(string methodName, IEnumerable<string> parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OracleDataContextAdapter.ExecuteMethodCall");

        return base.ExecuteMethodCall(methodName, parameters);
    }
}
```

So now I can do the following:

```
var db = new GeneratedSchemaContext(new OracleDataContextAdapter());
var result = db.ExecuteSampleProcedure();
```

1. Is there a more elegant way for achieving this task? What do you think about the solution?
2. Is this still the adapter pattern or have I misunderstood it?

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner and arguebly more elegant solution will be to use implement IDbMethodCaller with constrcutor injection of OracleDataContext. This way you wouldn't need to use new method modifier:

```
public class OracleDataContextAdapter : IDbMethodCaller
{


    private OracleDataContext dataContext;

    public OracleDataContextAdapter(OracleDataContext oracleContext)
    {

       this.dataContext =  oracleContext;  
    }

    public new IEnumerable<object> ExecuteMethodCall(string methodName, IEnumerable<string> parameters)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OracleDataContextAdapter.ExecuteMethodCall");

        return this.dataContext.ExecuteMethodCall(methodName, parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: DIP! Yeah I didn't see that. Thank you. Can you say something about the Adapter pattern thing? Is it a kind of adaptation and can I call the class like that? With the "Adapter" suffix?